# Где сохранять изображения, если устройство не предусматривает наличие SD-карты

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Требуется реализовать сохранение изображений в галерею устройства. На данный момент использую такой код для получения пути к этой папке:

```
public class FileUtil {

private static final String APP_DIRECTORY_NAME = "lounah";

private static final File savedPhotosExternalDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), APP_DIRECTORY_NAME);

private static final File savedPhotosInternalDir = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), APP_DIRECTORY_NAME);

private FileUtil() {}

// TODO: fix crush, when external is unavailable
public static File savedPhotosDirectory() {

    File savedPhotosDir = null;

    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        if (!savedPhotosExternalDir.exists()) savedPhotosExternalDir.mkdir();
        savedPhotosDir = savedPhotosExternalDir;
    } else if (!savedPhotosInternalDir.exists()) {
            savedPhotosInternalDir.mkdir();
            savedPhotosDir = savedPhotosInternalDir;
        }
    return savedPhotosDir;
}
```

}

Проблема в том, что этот код прекрасно работает, если устройство предусматривает наличие SD карты, но если ее нет (Google Pixel 2, Sony Xperia A1, например), то и externalStorageDirectory тоже нет. Куда в таком случае сохранять изображения?

Comment: Это же очевидно - нужно сохранять во внутреннюю память. Да и вообще так нужно делать всегда. Это сам пользователь должен решать, куда ему сохранять фотографии, а не ваше приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Если устройство не располагает `External Storage` (внешняя память), то в таком случае можно сохранять в `Internal Storage` (внутренняя память устройства).

Подробнее можно почитать в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html)